# What is best approach to encrypting an encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, vigenere

For my CPSC class, I need to make encryption code using caesar cipher.  That is done.  The next part is taking the encrypted message and cycling the secretKey to be added to the encrypted message.  For example, if I encrypt "Hello!" using a shift of 13, it will turn into "Uryyb!". Then I must shift "U" by one, "r" by three, "y" by one, etc... which will encrpt into "Vuzbc!" I am in a beginner class so I do not know all the cool tips and tricks.  Only possible solution I know is to take the outcome of the caesar cipher and somehow index the secret key to be added to the outcome.

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
public class Cipher { 

private int secretKey;
private int superSecretKey;


public static void main(String [] args)
{ 
    Cipher cipher = new Cipher(1);
}

public Cipher(int myKey) { 
    secretKey = myKey;
}


public String caesarEncrpyt (String s) {
    String r = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                r += (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
            else {
                r += (char) ('a' + (c - 'a' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
        }
            else {
            r += c;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

public String caesarDecrypt (String s) {
    String r = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                r += (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' - secretKey) % 26);
            }
            else {
                r += (char) ('a' + (c - 'a' - secretKey) % 26);
            }
        }
            else {
            r += c;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

public String augustusEncrypt (String s) {
    String r = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                r += (char) ('A' + (c - 'A' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
            else {
                r += (char) ('a' + (c - 'a' + secretKey) % 26);
            }
        }
            else {
            r += c;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

augustusEncrypt is a copy and paste of caesarEncrypt.  I've been moving some stuff around hoping for a solution.  Thanks in advance!

Edit: I may not have explained this correctly, if you have a question, I'll be here.

Comment: In general, encrypting encrypted text is bad practice. It's not likely to make anything more secure, and depending on the systems used might actually make things weaker. (obviously not a concern with this particular case, though clearly there's nothing more secure about this double-encryption)

Comment: When you say "cycling the secret key", do you mean that because the key was 13, you're going to turn that into {1, 3}, and if the key were 482213, the cycle would be {4,8,2,2,1,3}?

Comment: Kind of hard to explain.  If my secretKey were 13 and I had to rotate "Hello!" I would add 1 to H, then 3 to e.  Then repeat back to 1 to add to L.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function, call it `toDigits` which will take an int (or a long) and return an array of ints corresponding to the digits of the input. to toDigits(13)=>{1,3} and toDigits(4834)=>{4,8,3,4}, etc

Then write a function `encryptChar`, taking a char and an int and encrypting the char by that int. (encryptChar('e', 1)=>'f', encryptChar('a',28)=>c, etc)

Then you can loop over the characters of the message and the digits in this array, passing the values to encryptChar and use the results to assemble your encrypted message. In a loose sort of pseudocode:

```
fn encryptMessage(message, key):
  key_array = toDigits(key)
  output = ""
  for i in length (message):
    output.append(encryptChar(message[i], key_array[i % length(key_array)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practices and conventions for encrypting *aside*, the solution is simple.

You have letters A-Z and a-z which already perform the correct loop when we step off of the alphabet, and you believe you have that working correctly.  All you need to do is add 1 *before* you loop around.

It would be something like this (warning: untested):

```
('A' + ((c+1) - 'A' + secretKey) % 26)
```